# Powershell Loop stuck in data stream

Tags: powershell

I created a powershell script that gets the content of a text file to form an array, iterate through the list and perform an nslookup on each server in the list and then I need it to output to a txt file. I can get it to do everything except get the data to the output stream and into the txt file.

I'll give you what I have done so far as well along with some of the code :)

```
$serverlist = Get-Content'c:\users\username\desktop\serverlist.txt'
```

I pass it through to a for each loop to attempt to iterate through each item in the list and pass it to nslookup so it does a dns query for each server in the list.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content'c:\users\username\desktop\serverlist.txt'

foreach($server in $serverlist)
{
   nslookup $server
}
```

This actually works REALLY well within the powershell client. The problem is I can't seem to get the output from the console after its completely done with the loop to print out to a text file.

I'm dealing with a massive amount of lookups which is the why I'm dealing with this script.

I've tried `write-host`, I've tried `out-file` and I have tried `script > domainlist.txt` with no avail.

I suspect that it is stuck in the data stream and doesn't know where to go.

I even tried something like the following:

```
$serverlist = Get-Content'c:\users\username\desktop\serverlist.txt'
$domainlist = Out-file -path 'c:\users\username\desktop\domainlist.txt'
foreach($server in $serverlist)
{
  nslookup $server
}

script > $domainlist.
```

I've tried breaking it down by the loop in isesteroids which helps a lot but it doesn't tell me what may be going on with data streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell confusingly has two different `foreach` constructs.  There is the `foreach ($var in $collection)` statement, which you are using above, and there is the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet.

```
# Statement foreach
foreach($server in $serverlist) {
  nslookup $server
}

# Same loop using cmdlet foreach.  
# The current item is stored in the special variable $_
$serverlist | Foreach-Object {
  nslookup $_
}
```

The reason you aren't able to redirect the output is that the statement foreach does not output to the PowerShell pipeline.  **One way to work around this is by switching to the cmdlet foreach.**

Another way to work around this is to redirect the output of `nslookup` directly, rather than redirecting the entire loop, using the `>>` append redirection operator.

```
del domainlist.txt
foreach($server in $serverlist) {
  nslookup $server >> domainlist.txt
}
```

This adds the output from `nslookup.exe` to the end of the `domainlist.txt` file each time it's run.

One note on `nslookup`:  On a bad lookup, `nslookup` command sends errors to the `stderr` stream, rather than `stdout`.  To capture these errors, you will need to redirect the error stream into the output, using `2>&1`

```
nslookup $server 2>&1 >>domainlist.txt
```

As a side note: Because PowerShell is a scripting language with implicit statement breaks on line breaks, you should really get in the habit of putting the opening curly brace on the end of the line, rather than on the next line.  If your first line is somehow a complete statement, you can get very hard to debug problems because it doesn't bind to the scriptblock on the following line.

Answer (score 0):

Output directly to the file within the loop body:

```
foreach($server in $serverlist)
{
    nslookup $server |Out-File C:\output.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: I would advise against assigning the entire loop to a variable when doing a "massive amount of lookups", as the entire output has to go into memory before being passed to out-file.  Outputting to the pipeline or within the loop body are preferable.

Comment: I actually used the for-each object piped to an Out-File. Here was the final code I implemented. 'code' $serverlist | ForEach-Object {nslookup $_} | Out-File $domainlist. I'm a new user to stack overflow sorry if my "code" editing skills aren't there to enter into the web form just yet. I'll be looking for an FAQ :)